# Default project screen with Cordova on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I have built a project written in Cordova/PhoneGap for iOS and I can only see default screen with Cordova logo. What do I have to set in XCode to copy files in www directory to cordova project stub?

Comment: The file `platforms/ios/www/index.html` remains the default one - with the logo and device ready message. I have to copy content of directory `www` to the directory `platforms/ios/www`. Is there any command in Cordova to achieve this?

Comment: I found out that problem is in my gruntfile which doesn't copy/generate  files to project's `www` directory. I am sorry.